# Hybrid Azure Ad Join Automatic Device Sync Restriction

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Hi guys i want join only some of the devices in my OU to azure but sadly all the devices in that OU joining automatically to Hybrid azure AD even after GPO applied to that particular OU. how to prevent automatic enrollment of this Hybrid Device join? could you please help out on this?

is there any mechanism to sync devices based on attribute filter (white listing)?

Answer (score 0):

SCP(Service Connection Point) helps the device to find tenant-related information required for device registration. You have to remove the SCP (Service Connection Point) in your domain in order to a controlled validation. You can then create the registry keys required for this manually or through GPO on the devices that you want to join to Azure AD.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/hybrid-azuread-join-control

In your Scenario, where you want to join some number fo devices from an OU, you would have to create a GPO to create the registry keys and then apply WMI filters to decide which device gets the GPO based on your requirement.

Ref: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/09/11/fun-with-wmi-filters-in-group-policy/